# A good agile modelling tool?

Tags: architecture, agile, modeling, software-design

I am starting a new project and i want to use agile modelling instead of UML.

Although for UML i was always using DIA, do you have any tools to propose for Agile Modelling?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whiteboards.   Seriously though, what are you trying to accomplish?  Are you looking for a tool to help you communicate?  Are you looking for code-generation?  Are you looking for something to help you work out your architecture and design?  "Agile Modeling" is a tricky space to be in.  I have found doing architecture and design to be at odds with most people's idea of "Agile" development.  That doesn't mean I don't think you should do it, but I need to know *why* you want to do modeling before I can recommend tools.

For me, doing agile modeling is doing "running gunfight" modeling.  Each iteration doing as little modeling as possible so that the next iteration can succeed (and not destroy my overall architecture).  As such, the modeling tools you choose are fairly irrelevant.  It's just a communications medium, so anything that can draw UML and flowcharts is fine.  I actually really support the big whiteboard in the center of the room style of modeling.  It encourages iteration, and makes things highly visible.

If you are hoping to use modeling to generate your entire domain layer, then you might be in for some pain and suffering.  I have not seen that level of modeling succeed on an agile project (although I have several times on waterfall style projects).

Comment: Hello rob, thanks for the response! I am actually searching for a program that will help me Design my system's Architecture. Although i understand the efficiency of the whiteboards, issues like history tracking, and archiving or versioning keep me back from using it when i really want to design and document the architecture.

Comment: I hear you, but those things should be deprioritized in agile architecture.  That's a very fundamental difference between agile and waterfall methodologies.   I spend a lot of time convincing management that my diagrams should not be put into a searchable/versioned repo, and kept up to date for all time.  That they are almost all one-offs, and as such, should be discarded as soon as possible.  They are purely a communication mechanism.

Comment: Also to be fair, I do cheat on this a lot, and keep a lot of my older diagrams around so that I can copy/paste elements.  It is often easier to use older diagrams, and bring them up to current reality than it is to recreate them each time.